# How to append value into an element javascript to interact with an element using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When i use the following code the value in the element is replaced with the new value. I wanted to add on to it. Is there any command like append instead of setValue to add on or to insert any new line.

```
WebElement codeMirror = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='CodeMirror']"))
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(\"" + value + "\");", codeMirror);
```

Answer (score 0):

To My knowledge, there is no such function but you could break it into getting the value attribute first and then append the new value to it for assignment.

e.g

```
codeMirror.setAttribute('value', codeMirror.getAttribute('value')+StringToAppend);
```